# Firefox add-on to immediately store bookmark

Tags: gratis, firefox, bookmark, keyboard-shortcuts

I very often bookmark pages in Firefox in a 'Read later' folder.
This takes 3 actions:

- Hit Ctrl-D
- Pull open the Folder dropdown containing the last folders used
- Click on the 'Read later' folder

This assumes that the 'Read later' folder is in the last five folders used. If not, I have a lot more browsing to do.

I would love a (free) add-on that lets me save a bookmark to a pre-defined folder with one key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for the same and never found anything that suited my taste, so I made my own add-on (Pile): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pile-lightweight-bookmarking/

Comment: Nice. Together with [Total Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/total-bookmarks/) I now have a system to quickly store store bookmarks and sort them out later. One feature request: It should refuse to 'pile' duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but I think it solves the requirement.

Have you tried [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)? (has a [Firefox add-on](https://activations.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/pocket.html))

Comment: I'll check it out. I might as well look at Evernote then, that's on both machines I use most.

Comment: Pocket is integrated in Firefox

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. That way it lost many useful features (the drop-down list of saved articles, the indicator that a page was already bookmarked, the edit feature, and maybe more). And the original addon is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for something similar for quite some time, and recently I found addon [deskCut](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/deskcut/?src=ss) (Desktop Shortcut), which adds desktop shortcut creation to the context-menu. It is [quite old](http://deskcut.mozdev.org/), but it still works in newest FF. It doesn't have keyboard shortcut, but it has enough options for customization.